# The size of RDS on AWS is growing exponentially every day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I set up an RDS on AWS. I'm using the free domain for my trials. There is only one table in the database and there is very little data in the table. But when I enter the free space used, it increases by almost 2 GB every day. I think he backs up one instance of the database every day and I can't delete those backups. Is there a way to turn this backup off or have it taken monthly, weekly?

I get the following warning when I want to delete the snapshot. Do I have to disable RDS to delete it?

You can't delete a system snapshot. To remove system snapshots for an active DB instance, modify the DB instance and reduce the automated backup window. To remove system snapshots for a deleted instance, delete the retained automated backup.

Update: The backup period was selected as 1 day. I changed this. How can I delete past backups?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to be describing linear growth, not exponential growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a system snapshot manually, rather you can go to RDS, click Modify and go to Backup and change the Backup Retention Period to a lesser value, which will mean that old Snapshots will automatically get deleted after these many days or can keep 0 if you dont want any backup[image]

And if you want to delete older snapshots, if they dont get deleted by changing the period to 0, you would have to delete the RDS and check the box to delete its snapshots as well

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will the deletion process happen automatically after a certain time? Or will I have to delete it again? It was not deleted even though I set it to 0. Removing RDS shouldn't be a problem right now, but if I had a large database it would be a problem. Do you have an alternative suggestion for these situations?

Comment: Yes it will take sometime, and the snapshots will get deleted during the next scheduled backup cleanup process so might have to wait... If you want urgently, so need to delete the RDS, there is no other alternative to it... either set the backup retention period and wait for its job to run, or would have to delete RDS & recreate